# How to render data in a different partial

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am developing a module to create products and through ajax and remote: true it is displayed without updating the page.
I would normally do something like this in the create.js.erb:

```
$("#container_products").prepend('<%= j render @product %>'); 

$("#product_<%= @product.id %>").hide().fadeIn(500);
```

This would render the registry in a partial called "_product.html.erb" and would show it without reloading the page

But in this case the partial will not be in the same folder but in a subfolder called "folder_parcial", so I must specify in the render that the partial is in the subfolder in this way:

```
  $("#container_products").prepend('<%= j render(:partial => '/products/folder_partial/product', collection: @product) %>'); 
$("#product_<%= @product.id %>").hide().fadeIn(500);
```

But does not show me the record, what could be doing wrong?

this is my index:

```
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
      <thead>

    </thead>
    <tbody id="container_products">
      <%= render partial: "/products/folder_partial/product", collection: @products %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

this is my partial _product.html.erb in the folder "folder_partial"

```
<tr id="product_<%= product.id %>">
  <td class="component_name_body_col"><%= product.try(:id)%></td>
  <td class="component_name_body_col"><%= product.try(:Name)%></td>
</tr>
```

this is my create action:

```
 def create
      @product = Product.new(product_params)
      respond_to do |format|
        if @product.save
          format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'product was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
          format.js {flash.now[:notice] = '.'} #ajax

        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          format.js {flash.now[:alert] = '.'} #ajax

        end
      end
  end
```

Comment: Any errors, in the browser console or rails console?

Comment: @Iceman Does not show me any errors in the console, I think that rendering in the javascript I'm doing wrong but I do not know how it would be correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution

```
 $("#container_products").prepend('<%= j render(:partial => '/products/folder_partial/product', locals: { product: @product}) %>');
```